# symfony 2 Error:Call to a member function * on a non-object in *

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship

I have an entity Users

```
class Users
{
  //...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $firstname;

public function getFirstname()
{
    return $this->firstname;
}

/*
*@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity='Worksamples', mappedBy='user')
*/
private $worksample;

public function __constraction()
{
    $this->worksample = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getWorksample()
{
    $this->worksample;
}

}
```

and another one entity called Worksamples

```
class Worksamples
{
 //...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="sampleSource", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $samplesource;

public function getSamplesource()
{
    return $this->samplesource;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="UserId", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $userid;   

public function getUserid()
{
    return $this->userid;
}


/*
*@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="worksample")
*@ORM\JoinColumn(name="UserId", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $user;

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

}
```

in my controller i have this action

```
public function indexAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeWellcomeBundle:Users')
        ->find($id);

    $sample = $user->getWorksample()->getSamplesource();

    return $this->render('AcmeWellcomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('sample' => $sample));

}
```

and I have this error

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getSamplesource() on a non-object in ....

it supposed a User has many Worksamples and a Worksample has only one User.

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before using your code**

Did you run your classes through the console of your app? If not execute this in your terminal or a console through SSH on your Server:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities [YourVendorName]
```

Afterwards update your database using:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

And clear caches:

```
app/console cache:clear
```

Those steps will make sure that all annotations are actually used and your database is set up correctly.

Then: You don't need `private $userid;` in `Worksamples` and you don't need `$this->worksample = new ArrayCollection();` in `Users`. Doctrine will handle all this for your. Also it would be good to rename `$worksample` to `$worksamples` as it will always return an `arrayCollection` and never a single object.

When all is set up correctly, you can simply use `$workspace->getUser()` which will return an object of class `User` attached to this specific object.

**In your controller**

First of all get the list of worksamples. Then check whether any worksamples are attached to the object. Then for example get the vlue from the first object in the list:

```
$samples = $user->getWorksamples();
if ($samples) {
    $sample = $samples[0]->getSamplesource();
}
```

**Some notes:**

- The constructor of a class is called `__construct()` and not `__constraction()`.
- As a single object represents a user or a workspace, your classes should also be named `User` and `Wokrspace` in singular.

Comment: Thanks @insertusernamehere, the case "The constructor of a class is called `__construct()` and `not __constraction()`" in your notes was my problem :)